# Best practice to cache static datas (local files VS local SQL servers)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, caching

I'm working on a web form project with a SQL server 2012 to store my data.
The SQL server is placed in Europe and I have multiple web servers (IIS 8) around the world (USA / CHINA / etc..).

I have some articles that are statics or can be changed rarely (like once a week) but accessed thousands of times. To optimize requests on these articles, a local file (XML) on each IIS is used to store data and the local file is updated for each update of the articles. Is it a reliable solution ? and why ?

In case of having a local SQL server that could be set as readonly. will it be faster to reach data from the local file (XML) or from the local SQL server ? and why ?
In case of the local SQL server to be the best solution, how much would it cost me for each SQL server ? (Which SQL server version/licence will be necessary ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is narrow down on which "database" is faster for local use.

For sure the XML is the slowest to read and write because is convert to string any data, and back the data to string and this is a slow operation compare it with binary read/write - [Comparing PROTOBUF, JSON, BSON, XML with .NET](http://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/comparing-protobuf-json-bson-xml-with-net-for-file-streams/). Also is slow because is not keep any kind of cache, have no indexes to search for, have no optimize at all by himself.

Any other database is faster than save to XML files you data, and not that much complicate than the XML save data.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this but I wasn't sure about it. I would prefer to store datas in a SQL DB for the security/structured backup/cache, and as you said also for keeping type (Byte/DateTime/string/etc). Thanks for this clear and constructive answer.